# Install mysql-python on Mountain Lion

Tags: django, macos

I'm trying to install but i get this:

```
new-host-27:enquete felippe$ file /usr/local/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/local/bin/python (for architecture i386):  Mach-O executable i386
/usr/local/bin/python (for architecture x86_64):    Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
new-host-27:enquete felippe$ export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes
new-host-27:enquete felippe$ python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 77, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model, emit_post_sync_signal
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 27, in load_backend
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

So in order to consistently have MySQL and mysql-python working I do the following:

1. download and install xcode (https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)
2. go into XCode prefs and enable Command Line Tools
3. download and install Mysql Server Community Edition (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.5.html#downloads)
4. edit my bash profile

`nano ~/.bash_profile` and add the following:

```
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/mysql/lib
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

then I can `pip install MySQL-python` and it works.

The reason is that the python mysql driver requires mysql to operate. On other platforms there are packages you can install such as `apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` that fulfills the mysql requirement.